# When i click on a checkbox the element on the table turn to top, why? (React)

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem, if I am at the bottom of the table, when I click on a checkbox which can be inside the table or outside all the elements of the table go back to the first element of the table, why?

There is my checkbox

```
<input
      type={"checkbox"}
      disabled={checkboxIsDisabled}
      checked={selection[0].some(
        (selected) => selected.id === key(item[link])
      )}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const id = key(item[link]) || "";
        return selection[1](
          e.target.checked
            ? selection[0].concat([{ id }])
            : selection[0].filter(
                (selected) =>
                  selected.id !== key(item[link])
              )
        );
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Your screen scroll back to the top when you pressed the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, when a checkbox is pressed the element in the table turn back on the top